# How do you make arrows in Far Cry Primal?

Tags: far-cry-primal

Just got to the point in Far Cry Primal where I get to explore on my own with out real restrictions. I am starting to run low on arrows, and it appeared at first you crafted them. Is there a way to craft more after the initial creation? Or do I have to loot them now? I have looked through the available menus and could not find anything.

Comment: which platform?

Comment: PC, but I just figured it out.....I feel kinda dumb now...going to give someone a chance to answer it though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open your weapon wheel (depending on your key mapping on PC, L1 on Playstation 4, LB on XBOX ONE), and then highlight your bow. You will then have a "Craft" option showing up. Just press the corresponding control (depending on your key mapping on PC, X on Playstation 4 and A on XBOX ONE), and you will be able to craft arrows. Each one of those will cost you one piece of wood to make.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This applies to every weapon that you have already crafted for the first time just as a note to anyone else.

Comment: Also as a note to other people that find this, for PC, the default key for your weapon wheel is `Q`

Answer (score -4):

On the PC:
Hold Q to bring up the weapon menu.
Then left mouse click on the bow to craft an arrow.
Click additional times to craft more arrows.
Finally, release Q to close the weapon menu.
You must first have crafted the bow in the craft menu (I), which it sounds like you have.

Comment: Does this answer say anything other than what's already said in the existing answer?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this question was answered well over a year ago.